# Trying to Concatenate two column values in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two columns in pandas dataframe based on certain conditions, but I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Below is what I am trying to do:

if df['Origin Region1'] == "EUR":
    df['Org_Region'] = df['Origin Region1'] + '' + df['Origin Region']
elif df['Origin Region1'] == "ASIA":
    df['Org_Region'] = df['Origin Region1'] ``+ '' + df['Origin Region']

Please help!
```

Comment: have you an example about your data?

Comment: Yes sure,
this is data I have:




Origin Region1 Origin Region
N AM  East
EUR East
ASIA S.E. Asia






and this is the result I want:

N AM (EAST)
N AM (EAST)
N AM (EAST)
N AM (EAST)
N EUR
N AM (WEST)
S EUR
N EUR
S EUR
N AM (WEST)
S.E. ASIA







also if you can tell me how can I put the East/West inside a bracket??

I tried this approach:
if [df['Origin Region1'].isin(['EUR', 'ASIA'])]:
    df['Org_Reg'] = df['Origin Region1'] + ' ' + df['Origin Region']




got the expected result but this is not a complete soln to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['Org_Region'][df['Org_Region1'].isin(['EUR', 'ASIA'])] = 
    df['Origin Region1'] + ' ' + df['Origin Region']
```

Comment: tried, got the expected result, thanks, also could you pls tell me how can I get it into below format:

N AM (EAST)
N EUR
N AM (WEST)
S EUR

Comment: @nipunika_jain Your format is not understoodable. Post samples **in the question** of the data before and after the change.

Comment: sure, but, the solution that you gave, this is changing data for all the regions in my column and not just for EUR and ASIA

Origin Region1 Org_Region Origin_Reg
N AM  (East) (East) N AM 
N AM  (East) (East) N AM 
N AM  (East) (East) N AM